# MVC - cannot convert from 'int' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Hi I am trying to filer customers where customer ids are selected from multi selected dropdown box; My controller where I am having above mentioned error

```
public ActionResult Create(CountryViewModel country)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectedItems = country.MenuCountry.Where(p => country.ContryIds.Contains(int.Parse(p.Value))).ToList();         
        try
        {
            CustomerClient CC = new CustomerClient();
            var result = CC.findAll();

            var matches = from customer in result
                          where selectedItems.Contains(customer.Id) // Here is error and saying cannot convert from 'int' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem
                          select customer;
           // ViewBag.listCustomers = CC.findAll();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My Customer class are give bellow

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(Name = "CustomerId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Please advise; many thanks

Comment: `selectedItems` would need to be of type `List<int>` (or `int[]`, etc`)

Comment: selectedItems.Any(s=> s.value==ccustomer.Id.ToString())

Comment: @MarkC. in asp.net mvc we have a class SelectListItem . I think user is using it to create dropdown list . It has a Text and value properties both are of type string

Comment: Hi My countryViewMovel like bellow 
 public class CountryViewModel
    {   
        public List<SelectListItem> MenuCountry{ get; set; }
        public int[] ContryIds { get; set; }

    }

Comment: @user3624511 try my answer let me know if this is what you wanted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please

```
 var matches = from customer in result
               where selecteList.Exists(a=>a.Value==  customer.Id.ToString())                          select customer;
```

Comment: Hi #Yashveer Singh 
I am having another issue; previously solved but again broken; Having error on 
List<SelectListItem> selectedItems = country.MenuCountry.Where(p => country.ContryIds.Contains(int.Parse(p.Value))).ToList(); ------- Saying Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: it seems that country.MenuCountry ha some valued which is null . I cannot tell you more becuase I dont have data and its is related to when you are paring the value .

Comment: Try this  :-     List<SelectListItem> selectedItems = country.MenuCountry.Where(p =>  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value) && country.ContryIds.Contains(int.Parse(p.Value))).ToList()

Comment: @user3624511 and I think I solved your original question . So if you have other error it better to ask a new question . Please mark this one if it solved the problem you mentioned in your question .

Comment: Sorry; still same problem 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: Sorry I can not go that far; to see your solution working; its breaking before

Comment: @user3624511 as I mentioned the error say that you are converting something to integer which which is eiter null or emply . You need to find which records has that value

Comment: ALso I cannot help you without looking at what data is present in your Country.MenuCountry .

Comment: tel me what is country.MenuCountry ? I think it is a select list . try to print out all values on your console and see if some values are non numeric or null .

Comment: @user3624511 :- Did you tried to print the values of you can share the screent shot of the database table from where you are taking this value or where you are actually adding items to this object .

Comment: public class CountryViewModel
    {   
        public List<SelectListItem> MenuCountry{ get; set; }
        public int[] ContryIds { get; set; }

    }

Comment: data is coming from webapi2

Comment: data is displaying and Create(CountryViewModel country) is receiving value from form

Comment: can you please share the json which is coming . and code where are you parsing the json

Comment: I really not understanding

Comment: ok let me explain again :- You recevie data from service then add this to List<SelectListItem> MenuCountry object . The problem is that in this list there might be some items which does not have numeric values . So when you try to convert  it to int it throws you error .

Comment: so you need to find first which tems are present in you MenuCountry who doesnot have value or non nu,eric values  then you can exculde and you query will run fine

Comment: I can see list of Country and their ids into the view 
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ContryIds, Model.MenuCountry, new { @class = "listbox" })

Comment: @user3624511  i am talking about List<SelectListItem> MenuCountry you are trying to cast its value to int not contryids . so look in that object . Any its beyond any help you can get on stack overflow .. I will take leave now .

Comment: would you mind If I will share with my project in GoogleDrive with you

Comment: I need to go now you can share I will have a look but from where I will get the data ?

Comment: I have local database mdf

Comment: @user3624511 If Yashveer wishes to continue assisting you - that's up to them. However, please desist from extended discussion asking for further discussion if they're not willing to do so. Thank you.

Comment: @user3624511 i looked  at ur code nd it seems when you post the data it is not properly coming the property country.MenuCountry is null and that is the reason why u are getting exception . my answer will work if you able to fix yor post method issue . So i request you to accpt my answer and raise a new question if you are not able to correct your post method .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CountryViewModel  looks like this

```
public class CountryViewModel 
{
  public List<SelectListItem> MenuCountry{ get; set; } 
  public string[] ContryIds { get; set; } 
}
```

Now you simply need to filter for that country. Simply use `country.ContryIds` to get the selected country ids (actually the name).

```
 public ActionResult Create(CountryViewModel country)
 {
    var CC = new CustomerClient();
    var result = CC.findAll(); // assuming this return a collection of Customer
    var matches = result.Where(x=>country.CountryIds.Contains(x.Country);
    // to do : return something
 }
```

Since the `Country` property is of `string` type, we need to make sure that the dropdown's options value is also string (the country (name) ?). So probably in your GET action which renders the view with the dropdown,

```
var countryOptions = new List<SelectListItem> {
  new SelectListItem { Value="USA", Text="USA"},
  new SelectListItem { Value="Canada", Text="Cananda" }
};
// to do : pass countryOptions  to the view to render the dropdown
```